# How to combine MathView and Persian text together with correct format in android studio

Tags: android

I have made a quiz application that contains mathematical formulas. I have succeeded to show formula with both mathjax and katex libraries. But i have faced with a problem to show mathematical formulas combined with Persion text and right-hand alignment. Why Persion text starts from left side or disordered format? By the way, thip app works properly offline.
Would anyone help me?